# Order a PHP Dropdown Menu by ID as Opposed to Alphabetical Order

Tags: php, mysql

I created a dropdown menu using PHP, which refers to a database for the items. The issue I'm having is that the list is in alphabetical order, and I would like it to be in order by the ID. In this case 'pf_id'.

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT pf_id, primary_function FROM primary_function;";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    echo "<html>";
    echo "<body>";
    echo "<select name='primary_function' id = 'primary_function'>";

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                  unset($id, $name);
                  $id = $row['pf_id'];
                  $name = $row['primary_function'];
                  echo '<option value="'.$name.'"> #'.$id.' '.$name.' </option>';

                }

    echo "</select>";
    echo "</body>";
    echo "</html>";
    ?>
```

Comment: `SELECT pf_id, primary_function FROM primary_function ORDER BY pf_id ASC`

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is as simple as changing the order of the results in the query you are using:

```
$sql = "SELECT pf_id, primary_function FROM primary_function ORDER BY pf_id;";
```

Note I added `ORDER BY pf_id`. This will change the order of your results to be on ascending ID.